# how to display Sender name on Message for Group chat in react native messaging app and dont show his name if next messages sent by him?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

i have messaging app in react native and it contains Group messaging. now i want to show the name of sender on particular message. i already showing name of the sender on message. but i want do like when there are multiple messages of him in a row show his name on first message only.

here is the screen shots.

[image]

look there is name displaying on all messages in 1st image.

now want to do like this so only show his name in first message only.

[image]

in flatlist where i used to diplay the name is like this,

```
`<Text numberOfLines={1} style={{
                              flexDirection: 'row',alignItems:'center',textAlignVertical:'center',
                              flexWrap: 'wrap', color: 'rgb(44,88,157)', fontWeight: '600',
                              paddingLeft: 0,
                              justifyContent: 'flex-start',
                            }}
                            >{item.sender_user_id.nick_name
                              }</Text>`
```

Comment: Can you share what have you already tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a `Message` component that has a boolean property `showName`

```
renderMessage(showName = true, name, body) {
    return <Message showName={showName} name={name} body={body}/>
}
```

**To display name on the first of several messages:**

1. In your messages render, use a variable that tracks the last message's sender ID.
2. Set `showName` to true when the last ID is undefined or is different.

*Example*

```
renderMessages(messages) {
    let lastSenderId = undefined;

    messages.map(message => {
        let showName = !lastSenderId || message.senderId !== lastSenderId;
        lastSenderId = message.senderId;
        renderMessage(showName, message.name, message.body)
    });
}
```

**To display name on the last of several messages:**

1. If there's no next message, show name
2. If the next message has a different sender, show name

*Example*

```
renderMessages(messages) {
    const lastIndex = messages.length - 1;
    messages.map((message, i) => {
        let showName = false;
        if(i === lastIndex) {
            showName = true;
        }
        else {
            const nextName = messages[i+1].name;
            if(message.name !== nextName) {
                showName = true;
            }
        }
        renderMessage(showName, message.name, message.body)
    });
}
```

Comment: name displays on first message. but i want to display it on last message.

Comment: messages[i+1].name returns undefined at last so wrap this in if condition with !==undefined.

Comment: You're welcome. The `if(i === lastIndex) {...} else {...}` should already guarantee the existence of messages[i+1] inside the `else`.

Comment: @Aaron I have a similar type of concern. However, in my case I have to group messages by date. Here is my issue if you have time https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66740640/display-avatar-on-the-last-current-message-in-case-of-subsequent-messages . Thank you!